# swift の良いデバッグ方法を教えて下さい

Tags: ios, swift, macos

普段はPHPで開発しております。
オブジェクトや配列なども var_dumpすれば中身が出力されるのですが、
swiftの場合このような関数はあるのでしょうか？
オブジェクトの中身を見るのが大変なので、うまい方法を教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLog(obj.description)
```

または

```
println(obj.description)
```

で変数objの中身をログ出力することができます。
objがStringでもArrayでもDictionaryでも、
Swiftで用意されているクラスであればいい感じに出力してくれます。

ただし、テキストで表現できないようなオブジェクト(画像等)の場合は
クラス名とインスタンスのアドレスのみの表示となります。

独自クラスでも大抵実装されていると思いますので、試してみる価値はあると思います。